# PHP if statement "if X and/or Y"

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a less clunky version of the following if conditional in a Wordpress theme. I am trying to figure out how to do it without opening and closing the style tag twice:

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color' )) : ?>
  <style>
    #branding {
        background: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'main_color', '#243964' )."\n"; ?>;
    }
    a:link {
        color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'main_color', '#243964' )."\n"; ?>;
    }
  </style>
  <?php endif ?>
  <?php if (get_theme_mod( 'links_color' )) : ?>
  <style>
    #wrapper a:link {
        color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'links_color', '#6C84B4' )."\n"; ?>;
    }   
  </style>
  <?php endif ?>
```

I tried to combine the two with the following:

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color' || 'links_color' )) : ?>
      <style>
        #branding {
            background: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'main_color', '#243964' )."\n"; ?>;
        }
        a:link {
            color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'main_color', '#243964' )."\n"; ?>;
        }
        #wrapper a:link {
            color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'links_color', '#6C84B4' )."\n"; ?>;
        }   
      </style>
      <?php endif ?>
```

But for some reason this doesn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answers are good but I think they're missing something.

The original code will:

- add certain styles if condition A is met.
- It will add additional styles if condition B is met.

Combining them like this:

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color') || get_theme_mod( 'links_color' )) : ?>
```

Fixes the error in the OP's attempt but the OP's attempt was not an exact solution to their original goal of simply printing `"less style tags"`.  This is because if either one of those conditions are met, BOTH styles will be applied.

(perhaps this is the desired functionality?)

Geralds answer is closer because it sticks to the original logic but it will always print a `STYLE` tag, regardless if it's met.  Given the original posters desire to "clean up their HTML", there can still be a better solution of posting a `STYLE` tag only if there's styles to print.

The solution would be to perform all the logic in PHP, add the HTML to a buffer and then print that buffer if it's not empty.  You could do this by using the actual buffer `ob_start()`or just saving the string into a variable.  I'll use the more straight forward "save to a variable" approach.

```
<?php
// initialize the buffer we'll save our style strings too
$buffer = '';
// save the styles to the buffer for main
if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color' )) {
    $buffer .= 
    "#branding {
         background: " . get_theme_mod( 'main_color', '#243964' ) . "\n
    }
    a:link {
         color: " . get_theme_mod( 'main_color', '#243964' ) . "\n
    }\n";
}
// save the styles to the buffer for link colors
if (get_theme_mod( 'links_color' )) {
    $buffer .= 
    "#wrapper a:link {
          color: " . get_theme_mod( 'links_color', '#6C84B4' ) . "\n
    }\n";
}

// verify there's styles to print and print them into a single STYLE tag
if(!$buffer) {
    echo "<style>" . $buffer . "</style>";
}
```

?>

This will:

1. Keep the same logic in terms of when additional styles are added
2. Only Print one `STYLE` tag
3. Only print a `STYLE` tag if there are styles to print

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color') || get_theme_mod( 'links_color' )) : ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color' || 'links_color' )) : ?>
```

should be

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color') || get_theme_mod('links_color') )) : ?>
```

Because `get_theme_mod()` is a function you pass parameters to it. You could change the function to accept several paramiters then you could call the function like :

```
<?php 
function get_theme_mod($main_color, $links_color) {
   // do stuff and return bool
}

if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color', 'links_color' )) : 
?>
```

Also it's not the main problem with what you're trying to do but you should terminate `<?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

After reading your post again, I guess this is what you try to achieve:

```
<style>
<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color' )) : ?>
    #branding {
        background: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'main_color', '#243964' )."\n"; ?>;
    }
    a:link {
        color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'main_color', '#243964' )."\n"; ?>;
    }
<?php endif ?>
<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'links_color' )) : ?>
    #wrapper a:link {
        color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'links_color', '#6C84B4' )."\n"; ?>;
    }   
<?php endif ?>

</style>
```

This will only show the wanted css code, depending on the theme options, but you will only have one `<style>` tag opening and closing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color' ) || get_theme_mod( 'links_color' )) : ?>
<style type="text/css">
<?php endif ?>
<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color' )) : ?>
#branding {
    background: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'main_color', '#243964' )."\n"; ?>;
}
a:link {
    color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'main_color', '#243964' )."\n"; ?>;
}
<?php endif ?>
<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'links_color' )) : ?>
#wrapper a:link {
    color: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'links_color', '#6C84B4' )."\n"; ?>;
}   
<?php endif ?>

<?php if (get_theme_mod( 'main_color' ) || get_theme_mod( 'links_color' )) : ?>
</style>
<?php endif ?>
```